# IFRAME doesn't get updated when the target changes

Tags: dynamics-crm-4

I've designed a static HTML file *donkey.html* and display it in the IFRAME I've added to a tab on my form. This works. However, I noticed that when the contents of the file change on the server, the displayed text doesn't - unless the user right-mouse it and selects *update*.

How to reoslve that?

On the same tab I have a picklist, the default option of which isn't pre-selected anymore. I believe the misbehavior started directly after I've added my IFRAME to the tab.

How to trouble-shoot it?

Comment: Sounds like simple browser caching of the IFRAME page.  Could you just set the META tags to turn caching off?  Some browsers could still ignore that, but with a static HTML page, don't have a lot of options.  See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19284819/caching-static-html-site.  I would highly recommend replacing the IFRAME with a div and rely on a tool like jQuery to do an AJAX refresh of the content when the user clicks on the tab...

Comment: This seems to be better link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers?lq=1

Comment: @DavidF Thanks for the suggestion. I'll play around with METAs. Sadly, since it's CRM 4, I'm bound to using an IFRAME, there's no functionality connectable to switching the tabs and we're not allowed to use jQuery the way I'd like. However I could cheat and load in the script in the static HTML and use it there... Weird situation, I know...   :)