# HTML5 manifest no caching

Tags: asp.net, html, caching

Hello I got a question regarding no caching within my .net web application. I got an XHTML web application which is running with the following metatags:

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1" />
<meta http-equiv="CACHE-CONTROL" content="NO-CACHE" />
```

I want to make this application a HTML5 valid application. After running it through the HTML5 validator it will output that those metatags are not valid.

I did some research on the internet and a lot of people suggest to use a manifest file like:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2016-03-18 time 10:30 UTC v 1.01 
NETWORK:
*
```

Where this basically says: for all files, do not read from cache but from network server. This sounds like the browser is not caching it at all. But a downside of this approach is that as been said in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32774798/1976975) that you need to update the manifest file each time you do a (partial) postback. Which does not sound a very nice proper way to do that.

So I searched for an alternative method by using HTTP headers through my IIS via `web.config` adjustments. I found a source that says that you can use the following method:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache" />
                <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
                <add name="Expires" value="-1" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

No I am wondering is this method a good approach in order to not cache my webapplication?

Answer (score 1):

CACHE MANIFEST is for offline web apps and it's not an easy stuff to use at all, and as far as I know isn't even recommended way to make offline apps.

If you don't want your page to be cached in browser, then configuring response headers would be the right approach.

To prevent browser from caching a page completely, you can set following headers:

```
Cache-Control:no-store
Cache-Control:no-cache
Pragma:no-cache
Expires:Fri, 18 Mar 1999 12:22:21 GMT
```

Note that **Pragma** header is for **HTTP 1.0**, and **Cache-Control:max-age** is equivalent to **Expires**, but **Cache-Control:max-age** has higher priority, so there is no reason to have them both of them simultaneously

Comment: Thanks so I could also add these headers through my web.config? In case I only want to trigger a certain application? BTW: Cache-control should contain no-store and no-cache?

Comment: Yes, you can add dose header into your server configuration and enjoy the benefits. I personally would set even three headers, just in case **Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate**
But according to Chrome source code, should work with just: **no-cache**

Answer (score 0):

Use the manifest file as you described, and update it with javascript:

Your manifest:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2016-03-18 time 10:30 UTC v 1.01 
NETWORK:
*
```

Javascript:

```
var appCache = window.applicationCache;
appCache.update();
```

A good start to use appcache: [A Beginner's Guide to Application Cache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But does this (using a manifest file) actually do the same as those metatags, which work within XHTML? And is not required to change the content of the manifest file to trigger the browser to read it again?

Comment: Yes, but an appcache can do a lot more. Plus, you often do not have access to the configuration of the webserver. An appcache file can simply be placed in your website folder.

Comment: Yep, thaks that sounds clear. But what I do not understand is why do I have to update each time I do a (partial) postback? I just want to disable caching and do not cache any files

Comment: Maybe what is proposing Kurt is forcing the update of related files included in your HTML page. Since we can easily tell to the browsers thanks to META tag that we don't want cache the HTML page... but is not such easy for files related. I'm gonna give a try and see if works. :))

Comment: Ops, using applicationCache is currently deprecated:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache

The talk, lost totally my interest. Let's move on with serviceWorkers.