# Disable browser caching HTML5

Tags: html, caching, cache-control, http-caching, no-cache

I would like to know how to disable the browser cache, using HTML5.

I found this useful post ([How to control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-to-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers/2068407)), but it contains the info only for HTML4 or other languages.

In my web application I use Java (**Spring Boot**) and **Thymeleaf** to produce HTML5.
I would like to understand what are the equivalent tags for HTML5, of the following HTML tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

It's fine either through HTML5 tags, or even through a Java side solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent html5 page from caching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228697/how-to-prevent-html5-page-from-caching)

Answer (score 0):

In order to disable the browser cache with HTML5, you can act on the Spring Security configuration class, as in the example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) {
   ...
   http.headers().cacheControl().disable();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For disable the browser cache with HTML5 in response header you can view this post [automatically add header to every response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16190699/automatically-add-header-to-every-response).
For application made in Spring annotation-based see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49431665/4939245